# How to mount NFS shares via /etc/fstab - Access denied by server while mounting

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab

I am trying to mount a NFS share to my OpenSUSE 13.1 Server on startup using /etc/fstab file with the following entry:

```
l00nim10:/export/werk/        /home/smbshares/nimshare_03/    nfs     vers=3  0 0
```

Unfortunately, this does not work! Using the command mount -a I keep on getting the error message

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting l00nim10:/export/werk/
```

I already tried adjusting the option attributes in fstab with a bunch of combinations such as rw, defaults, guest, vers=2, etc...
All in general leading to the presented error or to an "I/O error mounting". 
The strange thing about this is, that using the su command

```
mount -t nfs l00nim10:/export/werk /home/smbshares/nimshare_03 -o vers=3
```

works fine without any trouble. The thing is that I need to restore the mounts at startup in case the server goes down. Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Have you got some access/error logs available on the NFS server?

Comment: I am sorry, I am a newbie on this area... Could you help me out and tell me which logs might be interesting on the server?

Comment: Actually I've never admin'ed a NFS server, so I don't have a clue. I was just trying to collect information for real experts to answer your question :D

Comment: By the way, the system and version of your NFS server could help. Could you tell us more about the server ?

Comment: Oh sure, totally forgot about that! The NFS Server runs AIX 7.1

Comment: It could be that your DNS server is started late in the startup process. I think that when trying to mount the filesystems in `fstab`, the system isn't able to resolve `l00nim10` but by the time you run the `mount` manually, it is able to resolve the server name and thus succeeds. Why not add your server by IP to the `fstab` and try again?

Comment: Hey Joseph, thanks for the proposal. Tried replacing the serversname with it's ip, unfortunately this didn't bring any change... The strange thing is, that mount -a (which uses fstab as far as I know) is not working in opposite to the manual command posted in my questions. This really confuses me